# How to combine 2 .Each() lists into one array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying combine 2 lists to create one list using jQuery .each() for each of my elements.  Actually it is 2 table cells that are iterated through.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item One</td>
    <td class="time">item One Time</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item Two</td>
    <td class="time">item Two Time</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Current jQuery looks like this:

```
var allProductNames = [];
 $('.cart .name').each(function(){
   var cartProduct = $(this).text();
   allProductNames.push(cartProduct);
 });

 var allProductTimes = [];
 $('.cart .time').each(function(){
   var cartProductDateTime = $(this).text();
   allProductTimes .push(cartProductDateTime);
 });

 var allProductNamesList = allProductNames.join();
 var allProductTimesList = allProductTimes.join();
```

I then want my result to output as the following format

'item One : item One Time', 'item Two: item Two Time', etc.

I know I am almost there. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me how to join both arrays into the format I would like?

Comment: can you add classes into your markup where they should be?

Comment: Is the output format you want is a string or an array of strings?

Comment: Why do you want the string like that?  Can you change the HTML, because as it is, most answers will be fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `join`, use a `for` loop:

```
// where text will be accumulated
var text = "";
// loop through all names and times (should be of the same length)
for(var i = 0; i < allProductNames.length; i++) {
    // accumulate the text in the format you like
    text += "'" + allProductNames[i] + ": " + allProductTimes[i] + "',";
}
// remove the trailing ','
text = text.slice(0, -1);
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
var allProductNames = [];
 $('.name').each(function(){
   var cartProduct = $(this).text();
   allProductNames.push(cartProduct);
 });

 var allProductTimes = [];
 $('.time').each(function(){
   var cartProductDateTime = $(this).text();
   allProductTimes .push(cartProductDateTime);
 });

var text = "";
for(var i = 0; i < allProductNames.length; i++) {
    text += "'" + allProductNames[i] + ": " + allProductTimes[i] + "',";
}
text = text.slice(0, -1);
    
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item One</td>
    <td class="time">item One Time</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item Two</td>
    <td class="time">item Two Time</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am going with this solution because it got me exactly what I needed. I just needed to add the $.trim() around the $(this).text().

Answer (score 3):

I suppose one simple way is just to loop the `tr`s and construct the index out of the `name text` and the value from the `time text`.

```
var obj = {};

$('.cart tr').each(function(i, tr) {
  var $tr = $(tr);
  if ($tr.find('.product').text() !== "") {
    obj[$.trim($tr.find('.product').text())] = $.trim($tr.find('.MuseumDateTime').text())
  }
})
```

I've added `$.trim()` to remove the trailing and leading whitespace. I'v also ensured data is present in the columns to ensure you don't have blanks in your ouput.

[Have a look here](https://jsfiddle.net/344o1u4p/)

Comment: Shouldn't `arr` be an object (`{}`)?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Hmm. you're right. I've updated it. Oversight.

Comment: Then he can use `JSON.stringify` to get a string representaion.

Comment: I got the object, I then tried JSON.stringify(obj).  My console shows some very odd formatting

Comment: @ClosDesign try `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)` to make it look nicer.

Comment: @ClosDesign [here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hfbto35/) illustrating exaclty what he's hinting at.

Comment: @ClosDesign Show us some real HTML markup so I can modify the selector.

Comment: There you go. You can see it on this Fiddle happening the same way if you console.  https://jsfiddle.net/344o1u4p/

Comment: Ahh yes the trimming. i thought that might be the issue. I just wasn't sure how to resolve that part. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function:

```js
var arr = $.map($('.cart tr'),function(tr, i){
    return $(tr).find('.name').text() +':'+ $(tr).find('.time').text();
});

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class='cart'>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item One</td>
    <td class="time">item One Time</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="name">item Two</td>
    <td class="time">item Two Time</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Upvoting because it got me close. Thanks!